# php echo html - margin-left is not working

Tags: php, html, css

Well, in a .php file I echo some html (like a template) for every result (from search input):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  //image
  echo "<img id=" . '"' . "myImg" . '"' . "src=" . '"' . "showImage.php?image=" . $row['shortcutImage'] . '"' . "class=" . '"' . "imageList" .'"' . ">";
  //title
  echo "<h5 class=" . '"' ."titleResult" . '"' . ">".  $row['name_now'] . "</h5>";
  //area
  echo "<p class=" . '"'. "areaResult" . '"' . ">" . "Περιοχή: " . $row['area'] . "</p>";

  //break between results
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";
}
```

and the style

- `imageList` is for image
- `titleResult` is for the `<h5>`
- `areaResult` for `<p>`

```
    .imageList{
            margin-top: 10px;
            clear: both;
            width:100%;
            max-width:250px;
            float: left;
        }
        .titleResult{
            color: rgb(17, 17, 17);
            font-weight: 500;
            margin-left: 35px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        .areaResult{
            margin-top: 35px;
        }
```

and of course the output I have: (Images names and area is tests)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `margin-left` you specify for your `h5` element is not taken from the right edge of the image, but from the edge of the viewport (or whatever element these elements are in). If you want the margin to be from the edge of the image, you'll have to add the image width of `250px` to it. This happens because you have made your `img` a floating element.

It would be wise to place each set of image, header and area text in a `div` so you can do your margin measurements from that context. That way, you can also get rid of the `br` elements used for vertical spacing and use CSS instead.

For instance, you could do:

```
<div style="padding-left:280px; padding-bottom: 40px">
  <img src="..." style="float:left">
  <h5>Title</h5>
  <p>Area</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is what I want!